# SVG not showing up 01

Tags: html, svg

There is a link icon that's supposed to go between the shield with X (Gpp Bad) and the triangle with exclamation point. (Warning) But it just won't show up. And, when it was showing up before editing the code, the gradient on it won't show, either. It just remained black.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <head>
      <center>
        <div>
        <style id="armStyle">
          .arm-away, .arm-stay, .night-stay, .arm-away-bypass, .alarm {
  /* gradient and fallback color */
  fill: url(#arm) #d00202;
            }
    </style>
        <style id="settingsStyle">
          .settings {
  /* gradient and fallback color */
  fill: url(#settingsother) #595959;
            }
    </style>
        
         <style id="wifiOther">
          .wifi {
  /* gradient and fallback color */
  fill: url(#wifiOption) #87dce8;
            }
    </style>
        
       <style id="MAIL">
         .MAIL {
  /* gradient and fallback color */
           fill: url(#MAIL) #5BFDFD;
            }
    </style>
        </div>
        <!---->
        <div class="armscreen" style="display: none;"> 
          <br>
          <button class="back-button" onclick="back()">◀ Back</button>
          <br><br><br><br><br><br>
          <p class="armscreen-mode-text">Arm the system in <span class="arming-mode-text-type"></span> mode</p>
    <input type="text" maxlength="4" class="arm-code-entry">
          <br><br>
          <button class="keypad-code-number">1</button>
          <button class="keypad-code-number">2</button>
          <button class="keypad-code-number">3</button>
          <br>
          <button class="keypad-code-number">4</button>
          <button class="keypad-code-number">5</button>
          <button class="keypad-code-number">6</button>
          <br>
          <button class="keypad-code-number">7</button>
          <button class="keypad-code-number">8</button>
          <button class="keypad-code-number">9</button>
          <br>
          <!-- reference: 0 -->
          <button class="keypad-code-number">0</button>
          
        </div>
      <div class="header">
        <button style="float: left;" id="wifi" title="Network Settings" onclick="configureWifi()">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" height="24" fill="#87dce8" class="wifi"><path d="M4.504 13.572l-1.505-1.489c2.201-2.805 5.413-4.583 9.001-4.583s6.8 1.779 9 4.583l-1.504 1.489c-1.835-2.338-4.512-3.822-7.496-3.822s-5.661 1.484-7.496 3.822zm7.496.678c1.791 0 3.397.891 4.498 2.293l1.502-1.488c-1.467-1.869-3.608-3.055-6-3.055s-4.533 1.186-6 3.055l1.502 1.488c1.101-1.402 2.707-2.293 4.498-2.293zm0 2.25c-1.196 0-2.258.602-2.99 1.536l2.99 2.964 2.99-2.963c-.732-.935-1.794-1.537-2.99-1.537zm0-11.25c4.179 0 7.927 2.078 10.495 5.351l1.505-1.491c-2.935-3.739-7.217-6.11-12-6.11s-9.065 2.371-12 6.11l1.505 1.491c2.568-3.273 6.316-5.351 10.495-5.351z"/></svg></button>
        <div class="system-top-text-readonly-status" style="user-select: none;">
          <div class="status1">
            <span class="value">Ready To Arm</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button id="system-status" title="Ready To Arm">
          <!--disarmed-->
          <svg style="position:absolute;" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">
  <linearGradient id="disarmed" x2="0" y2="1">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#1dd82a" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#3aa53b" />
  </linearGradient>
            <span class="value"></span>
            <!--fault-->
    <svg style="position:absolute;" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">
  <linearGradient id="fault" x2="0" y2="1">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#88ff00" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#58a600" />
  </linearGradient>
      <span class="value"></span>
</svg>
          <svg style="position:absolute;" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">
  <linearGradient id="trouble" x2="0" y2="1">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ff8800" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#bd6500" />
  </linearGradient>
            <span class="value"></span>
</svg>  
          <style>
          .disarmed {
  /* gradient and fallback color */
  fill: url(#disarmed) #1c6c5f;
}
          
          </style>
          <style>
          .trouble {
  /* gradient and fallback color */
  fill: url(#trouble);
}
          
          </style>
          <style>
          .fault {
  /* gradient and fallback color */
  fill: url(#fault);
}
          
          </style>  
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="150px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="150px" fill="#disarmed" class="disarmed"><g><path d="M0,0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/></g><g><path d="M12,2L4,5v6.09c0,5.05,3.41,9.76,8,10.91c4.59-1.15,8-5.86,8-10.91V5L12,2z M15.5,14.09l-1.41,1.41L12,13.42L9.91,15.5 L8.5,14.09L10.59,12L8.5,9.91L9.91,8.5L12,10.59l2.09-2.09l1.41,1.41L13.42,12L15.5,14.09z"/></g></svg>
            <!--fault-->
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="150px" height="150px" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xml:space="preserve">
<g transform="matrix(4.3194 -4.2513 4.2513 4.3194 499.9994 499.9999)" id="8194">
<g style="" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke">
        <g transform="matrix(6.25 0 0 6.25 0 0)">
<path fill="none"; transform=" translate(-12, -12)" d="M 0 0 h 24 v 24 H 0 V 0 z" stroke-linecap="round"></g>
</g>
        <g transform="matrix(6.25 0 0 6.25 0 0)">
<path transform=" translate(-12, 12)" d="M 17 7 h -4 v 2 h 4 c 1.65 0 3 1.35 3 3 s -1.35 3 -3 3 h -4 v 2 h 4 c 2.76 0 5 -2.24 5 -5 s -2.24 -5 -5 -5 z m -6 8 H 7 c -1.65 0 -3 -1.35 -3 -3 s 1.35 -3 3 -3 h 4 V 7 H 7 c -2.76 0 -5 2.24 -5 5 s 2.24 5 5 5 h 4 v -2 z" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
</g>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
          <!--trouble-->
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="150px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="150px" class="trouble" fill="#trouble"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path><path d="M1 21h22L12 2 1 21zm12-3h-2v-2h2v2zm0-4h-2v-4h2v4z"></path></svg>
            
            <br>
          <div class="button-status">Ready To Arm</div>
          <!-- svg code must be separate -->
        </button>
        <div>
          
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 96 960 960" width="24"><path d="M450 618V212h60v406h-60Zm30 320q-74 0-139.5-28.5T226 832q-49-49-77.5-114.5T120 578q0-80 34-149.5T250 305l42 42q-53 43-82.5 102.5T180 577.978Q180 703 267.5 790.5 355 878 480 878q125.357 0 212.679-87.5Q780 703 780 577.978 780 509 750.5 448.5 721 388 670 347l43-42q60 51 93.5 122T840 578q0 74-28.5 139.5t-77 114.5q-48.5 49-114 77.5T480 938Z" fill="#00ff00"></path></svg>
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 96 960 960" width="24"><path d="M284 779h60V504h-60v275Zm166 0h60V373h-60v406Zm166 0h60V631h-60v148ZM120 936V216h720v720H120Zm60-60h600V276H180v600Zm0 0V276v600Z" fill="#00ff00"></path></svg>
          <!--Home icon-->
          
          <details>
            <summary>More statuses</summary>
            <criteria>
              <span class="c-homeaway"></span>
              <span class="arm-status"></span>
            </criteria>
            <br>
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" fill="#000000"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12 3 2 12h3v8h5z"/></svg>
     <!-- divider -->   
          <!-- Lock icons -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" fill="#00ff00"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"></path><path d="M20 8h-3V6.21c0-2.61-1.91-4.94-4.51-5.19C9.51.74 7 3.08 7 6h2c0-1.13.6-2.24 1.64-2.7C12.85 2.31 15 3.9 15 6v2H4v14h16V8zm-2 12H6V10h12v10zm-6-3c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2s-.9-2-2-2-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2z"></path></svg>
          </details>
</div>
      <br>
      <button id="armAway" onclick="alertArmAway()" class="mainOptions">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="60px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="60px" fill="none" class="arm-away"><g><path d="M0,0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/></g><g><path d="M12,2L4,5v6.09c0,5.05,3.41,9.76,8,10.91c4.59-1.15,8-5.86,8-10.91V5L12,2z M10.94,15.54L7.4,12l1.41-1.41l2.12,2.12 l4.24-4.24l1.41,1.41L10.94,15.54z"/></g></svg>
        <br>
        Arm Away
        </button>
        <button id="armedStay" onclick="alertArmStay()" class="mainOptions">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="60px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="60px" fill="none" class="arm-stay"><g><rect fill="none" height="24" width="24"/></g><g><g><path d="M17,11c0.34,0,0.67,0.04,1,0.09V6.27L10.5,3L3,6.27v4.91c0,4.54,3.2,8.79,7.5,9.82c0.55-0.13,1.08-0.32,1.6-0.55 C11.41,19.47,11,18.28,11,17C11,13.69,13.69,11,17,11z"/><path d="M17,13c-2.21,0-4,1.79-4,4c0,2.21,1.79,4,4,4s4-1.79,4-4C21,14.79,19.21,13,17,13z M17,14.38c0.62,0,1.12,0.51,1.12,1.12 s-0.51,1.12-1.12,1.12s-1.12-0.51-1.12-1.12S16.38,14.38,17,14.38z M17,19.75c-0.93,0-1.74-0.46-2.24-1.17 c0.05-0.72,1.51-1.08,2.24-1.08s2.19,0.36,2.24,1.08C18.74,19.29,17.93,19.75,17,19.75z"/></g></g></svg> 
          <br>
          Arm Stay
        </button>
        <button class="mainOptions">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="60px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="60px" fill="#FFFFFF" class="settings"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M19.44 12.99l-.01.02c.04-.33.08-.67.08-1.01 0-.34-.03-.66-.07-.99l.01.02 2.44-1.92-2.43-4.22-2.87 1.16.01.01c-.52-.4-1.09-.74-1.71-1h.01L14.44 2H9.57l-.44 3.07h.01c-.62.26-1.19.6-1.71 1l.01-.01-2.88-1.17-2.44 4.22 2.44 1.92.01-.02c-.04.33-.07.65-.07.99 0 .34.03.68.08 1.01l-.01-.02-2.1 1.65-.33.26 2.43 4.2 2.88-1.15-.02-.04c.53.41 1.1.75 1.73 1.01h-.03L9.58 22h4.85s.03-.18.06-.42l.38-2.65h-.01c.62-.26 1.2-.6 1.73-1.01l-.02.04 2.88 1.15 2.43-4.2s-.14-.12-.33-.26l-2.11-1.66zM12 15.5c-1.93 0-3.5-1.57-3.5-3.5s1.57-3.5 3.5-3.5 3.5 1.57 3.5 3.5-1.57 3.5-3.5 3.5z"/></svg>
          <br>
          Settings
        </button>
          <button class="mainOptions" id="open-notificationsMAIL">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="60" viewBox="0 96 960 960" width="60" fill="none"><path d="M80 896V256h800v640H80Zm400-302L140 371v465h680V371L480 594Zm0-60 336-218H145l335 218ZM140 371v-55 55Z"></path></svg>
            <br>
            Message
          </button>
      <svg style="position:absolute;" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">
  <linearGradient id="arm" x2="0" y2="1">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#eb0505"></stop>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#bd1313"></stop>
  </linearGradient>
</svg>
        
        <svg style="position:absolute;" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">
  <linearGradient id="settingsother" x2="0" y2="1">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#c0c0c0"></stop>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#595959"></stop>
  </linearGradient>
</svg>
      
        <svg style="position:absolute;" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">
  <linearGradient id="wifiOption" x2="100%" y2="0%">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#b6c2c8"></stop>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#87dce8"></stop>
  </linearGradient>
</svg>
          
      
        
      
        <footer id="footer" class="myFooter">
          <button id="delay">Delay</button>
         &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
          <iframe src="https://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i82y1s0q/n784/fn3/fs18/fcfff/tct/pct/ahr/ts1" frameborder="0" width="55" height="22" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
          <iframe src="https://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i82y1s0q/n784/fn3/fs18/fcfff/tct/pct/tt1/tw0" frameborder="0" width="136" height="22" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
          <button id="back">Back</button>
        </footer>
    
      
      </center>
    </head>
  </body>
</html>
```

I edited the code to try to make the gradient show but it just made the entire path not show.

Maybe there was an accidental merge like 2 elements having the same class name.

Comment: There is a group <g> wrapping the link icon. This group has a transformation. If you remove the transform attribute of the group you will see a small link icon